# Proving a $2$-dimensional smooth surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Show that the level-set $S_F(0)$ $$F: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R, F(x,y,z) = 3xz+e^{y}+ye^z$$ is a smooth $2$-dimensional surface.

Computing the gradient I get that $\nabla F(x,y,z)=(3z,e^y+e^z, 3x+ye^z)$. However, I cannot seem to find the definition to show that this would be smooth. Should I consider the implicit function theorem here to compute the Jacobian of the parametrization and look at the rank of the matrix?

Comment: What is your definition of "smooth surface"? Or by "I cannot seem to find the definition to show that this would be smooth" did you mean you can't find a definition in your book/notes?

Comment: I cannot find it on the notes and trying to google it I'll just end up with differential geometry and some higher mathematical terminology which isn't covered in the Analysis II course.

Comment: I think there might be some conflicting definitions, but one sentence that [came up](https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/lisse/lisse.shtml#:~:text=A%20surface%20is%20said%20to%20be%20smooth) when I did a google search for `a surface is smooth if` was "A surface is said to be *smooth* if it does not have singular points, in other words, if it has a (unique) tangent plane at every point."

Comment: Yes, you want to apply the implicit function theorem. As long as the gradient vanishes at no point of your level surface, the implicit function theorem guarantees that the level set is locally a smooth graph at each point, and that tells you you have a smooth surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin By vanishing gradient do you mean that no component is zero or that all of the components cannot be zero? It seems that the first component and last component can be zero if $z=y=0$.

Comment: Something vanishes if it equals the relevant version of $0$. In this case the gradient vanishes if it equals the zero vector $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{0}$.

Comment: And since it cannot because of $e^y + e^z$, one can conclude that the surface is indeed smooth?

Comment: Yes, Daniel. Indeed, from that observation we see that locally at every point you can write the surface as $y=\phi(x,z)$ for a smooth function $\phi$. This will tell us (although you aren't expected to prove this) that it's globally a graph over the $xz$-plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin In the definition of the implicit function theorem, I cannot find that it would state that $\phi$ would be a smooth function. Is this always the case?

Comment: You'd better look at a careful statement. If $F$ is $C^k$ ($k$ times continuously differentiable), then $\phi$ is $C^k$. Thus, if $F$ is smooth (i.e., $C^\infty$), as yours is, then $\phi$ is smooth as well. (P.S. You might want to check out some of my YouTube videos, linked in my profile.)

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the comments.

Comment: @TedShifrin Small follow up. The implicit function theorem requires that $F(0,0,0) = 0$ in order to hold. It seems that in this particular case $F(0,0,0) = 1$. Could there be a mistake in the problem statement?

Comment: Any constant $c$ is fine. Replace $F$ with $F-c$.